# PHP superglobal $_FILES[] setted even if not set

Tags: php, image, file, input

OK, so I am making a blog in php, and in Admin Panel I have a section where I can post something and after that I can also edit a post to modify it's content/title/tags/photo etc.

The problem is that in the editing section I want to also edit the post's image. 
So I've made this:

```
$post_image = $post->post_image;

if(isset($_FILES['image']['name'])) {
           $post_image = ($_FILES['image']['name']);
                $post_image_temp = ($_FILES['image']['tmp_name']);
                $imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($post_image,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));

                if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif" && $imageFileType != '' && !empty($imageFileType)) {

                    $message .= "<p class='text-danger bg-light'>Only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF file formats are allowed. Your file format: <b>{$imageFileType}</b>.</p>";
                    $error ++;

                }
                move_uploaded_file($post_image_temp, "../images/{$post_image}");

            }
... 
... 
$post->post_image = $post_image;
$post->update()
```

What I supposed this to be doing is, firstly, set $post_image to the actual post image (from $post->post_image) and then **only if it is set a new image**, set that $post_image as the new image.

But, the problem is that php evaluates **true** that condition: `if(isset($_FILES['image']['name))` even if I don't post anything in that  that looks like this: `<input type="file" name="image" id="image" />`. So, even if I don't input any new image, the condition is true, and $post_image will become an empty string and saving that in the database, the new post image will become an empty string and won't shown anything.

So, if I want to edit only the title of a post, it will also edit the post image to an empty string and will display nothing in the posts section.

What am I doing wrong? How $_FILES works in this context? Why is it set even if I don't input an image?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use isset($_FILES['image']['name'] && $_FILES['image']['name']!="") as the condition, so you wont accept empty strings from your form, remember to update the filename in your db ONLY if the value is not ""

Comment: You can combine that into one test with `if (!empty($_FILES['image']['name']))`

Comment: Where is your CSRF token validation ?

Comment: You could as part of your checks use `$_FILES['image']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE` for a no-file upload.

Comment: Thanks for answers! I solved it that way, but I was just wondering why this was happening. OK, I sort of figured that out. @RambarunKomaljeet I am interested in learning more about CSRF token validation for security reasons. Do you have any tutorial or something for me from where to start into this?

Comment: Lookup volnix/csrf on packagist.org, its documentation should be good enough :)